# How can I attach fragment to MainActivity? Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-fragments, virtual-functions

I'm getting an error (Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference) when I'm trying to execute

```
FragmentThree f = (FragmentThree) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
        f.displayReceivedDataLanLon(message);
```

Here's how it looks like in whole class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentOne.SendMessage, FragmentOne.SendMessageLanLon {

    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    @Override
    public void sendData(String message) {
        String tag = "android:switcher:" + R.id.viewPager + ":" + 1;
        FragmentTwo f = (FragmentTwo) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
        f.displayReceivedData(message);
    }

    @Override
    public void sendDataLatLon(String message) {
        String tag = "android:switcher:" + R.id.viewPager + ":" + 2;
        FragmentThree f = (FragmentThree) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
        f.displayReceivedDataLanLon(message);
    }
}
```

and here's the ViewPagerAdapter

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        if (position == 0) {
            fragment = new FragmentOne();
        } else if (position == 1) {
            fragment = new FragmentTwo();
        } else if (position == 2) {
            fragment = new FragmentThree();
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
```

Someone that fragment manager cannot find my fragment, which probably means it hasn't been attached yet. But I do not know how I can do that or if this is the problem for sure..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```

This method can solve your problem. But I suggest you try to extends `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentPagerAdapter`. It will be retain your pager state.

**Update my test**: 
I put some code in onCreate() method and everything is ok:

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);

Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         sendData("test message");
         sendDataLatLon("test message");
     }
}, 3000);
```

Maybe two method `sendData` and `sendDataLatLon` be called when the Fragment have not created yet, try to check it.

Comment: where should I put it? In MainActivity?

Comment: after you grab viewPager instance. In your case the answer is going to be YES.